# collapsible div css - need it so start closed

Tags: html, css, collapsable

I have a collapsible dive which is working fine, however I want it to appear closed on default, as currently the element is on display when entering the page.

how can I alter this css I found to make the collapsible item closed at default?

here is the css

```
/*
 CSS for the main interaction
*/
.accordion > input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}
```

```
  <section class="accordion">
   <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1" checked="checked">
   <h2 class="handle">
     <label for="handle1"> text</label>
   </h2>
   <div class="content">
     <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> text </p>
     <p><strong>History:</strong> text</p>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hi, Please include your HTML and JS code as well. Thanks

Comment: @John Ive included the html code, there isnt any javascript

Comment: Ok I've added an answer. Please look

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove `checked="checked"` on the `input` in HTML and you're good to go.

```css
.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle1"> text</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> text </p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your collapsible div is .accordion .content so you would need to have the following as part of your css

```
.accordion .content {
   display:none;
}
```

I'd need to look at your html and js code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided the javascript isn't actually doing anything.
Here I got your code working with the following html... (I increased the transition time to 1s so the effect is more visible).

```css
.accordion > input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}
.accordion > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.accordion label {
  display: block;
}
.content {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion">
    <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1">
    <h2 class="handle">
        <label for="handle1"> text</label>
    </h2>
    <div class="content">
        <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> text </p>
        <p><strong>History:</strong> text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";  } }); }
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Click to Expand</button>
```

Comment: You get an error when pressing "Run code snippet" in your answer. In a Stack Snippet, you _do not_ include the `<script>` tags in the "Javascript" section of the snippet.

Comment: Please ensure code examples "work" before posting as an answer. (It doesn't work even after removing the snippet's `<script>` and `<style>` tags.)  see also, [answer]